# How to connect XAMPP MySQL to ADO.NET Entity Framework using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, xampp, ado.net

I am creating a project with ASP.NET and which would be connected on our University website and their currently using XAMPP MySQL on their system so I need to adjust on their database technology at the same time I want to implement Entity Framework of C# for faster development. Thanks you.

Ive already tried adding references on the project like MySQL.Data and installing MySQL Connector for Visual Studio but turns out it is for the MySQL not the XAMPP MySQL.

Comment: There’s no “XAMPP MySQL”, there’s just MySQL. What problems did you have connecting to it?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Sir the one included when installing XAMPP thats the database I need to be able to work on Entity Framework for my project

Comment: And it’s MySQL, just like any other. It’s not “XAMPP MySQL”, it’s MySQL. So what problems did you have when using the packages you mentioned to connect to it?

Comment: When creating ADO.NET Entity Data Model the is no MySQL on the Data Source when I try to change it.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem. On the "Entity Data Model Wizard" when I choose "EF Designer from database" then click "New Connection" if I try to change Data Source the "MySQL Data Provider" is not on the list. I have already installed Connector Net and MySQL for VS. Im not sure maybe I need a specific versions of the drivers. Im currently using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to your MySQL db in Visual Studio by going to the **Server Explorer** and click on the **Connect to Database**. Then select **Microsoft ODBC Data Source** and click continue. Make sure you enter your connection string.
This might be of help to you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhqknuizUKk

Comment: Hi Thanks for this but I encountered another problem. I was able to use Microsoft ODBC Data Source (ODBC). But I cant seem to see the MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver. Should I install something like a driver?

Comment: Use the MySQL Connector driver you installed

Comment: How do I use it? I already installed that MySQL Connector. I also installed a new driver from this https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.2.html but MySQL ODBC Unicode Driver still doesnt show on the Data Source.

Comment: Have you also tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=122&v=K3GZidOwGmM

Comment: I was able to make it work now and able to add it on the Server Explorer but the problem is still the same there is no Data Source for MySQL when I try to create ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: are you trying to access the db from localhost or from a remote connection on your school server?...if its remote, then you need to use the IP Address of the server instead of localhost

Comment: No its from my localhost since its still on development I have narrowed down the problem. On the "Entity Data Model Wizard" when I choose "EF Designer from database" then click "New Connection" if I try to change Data Source the "MySQL Data Provider" is not on the list. I have already installed Connector Net and MySQL for VS. Im not sure maybe I need a specific versions of the drivers. Im currently using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.